# Can I put my Skype notifications on my secondary monitor?

Tags: skype

I've just upgraded my Skype to version 5.

I get the new notifications in the top right of my primary monitor. My main Skype window is always on my secondary monitor.

I had a look at the options...

[image: Skype Notifications Preferences]

...but nothing seems to let me place it on my secondary monitor.

Is there a way to do this somehow? Any *advanced options* hidden somewhere?

Thanks